# my frontend and backend are not sharing cookies

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, mern

I've been trying to get my frontend and backend to share cookies but the server never actually get them.

my frontend has credentials include on it

```
const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/v1/auth/register', {
  method: 'POST',
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
});
```

and my backend have my core like

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```

and they still don't send cookies!

even tho I have a route that sets the cookie on the frontend from the backend

```
    res.cookie('auth-token', token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 86400,
    });
```

and it works perfectly fine after I used cors.

my check auth middleware:

exports.verifyAuth = async (req, res, next) => {

```
  try {
    const token = req.cookies['auth-token'];

    if (!token) {
      return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'No token, authorization required.' });
    }

    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

    req.user = decodedToken.user;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).json({ msg: 'No token, authorization required.' });
  }
};
```

EDIT:

- I was debugging it and apparently its always the first ever time that it doesn't send the cookies and that's because I'm using **getInitialProps** to send the request but I'm guessing that the request happens before cookies are loaded so I'm trying to find a way to pass the cookies to the request manually because fetch doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this config: {withCredentials: true}

Comment: credentials: 'include' in fetch equals withCredentials in axios.

Comment: its okay! :) I actually think i found what the problem is, ill be updating the question if u don't mind giving it a look